# Is it possible to invert this function?

Tags: inverse, inverse-function, newton-raphson

Sorry if I'm asking a stupid question, please bear with me :)

I have this function:

$$f(x) = x + A e^{Bx}$$

where A and B are known constants

Is it possible to find an inverse to this function?

(Even if in an iterative way, like using Netwon-Raphson method for example)

Comment: It depend on $A$ and $B$...

Comment: You can probably do it using the Lambert W function. It is a specific inverse, of $g(x)=xe^x.$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function?wprov=sfti1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write it in terms of the [Lambert W function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function?wprov=sfti1)

If $y=x+Ae^{Bx},$ then:

$$(y-x)e^{-Bx}=A.$$
Multiply both sides by $Be^{By}$ gives:
$$B(y-x)e^{B(y-x)}=ABe^{By},$$
giving $$B(y-x)=W\left(ABe^{By}\right)$$ or $$x=y-\frac1B W\left(ABe^{By}\right).$$

Since the W function can’t be written in terms of the so-called elementary functions, your inverse cannot, either, unless $AB=0.$